Rendering markdown content within Looker text box
I am trying to build a report in Looker, where one column happens to have text content in markdown file format. For example consider a 'student' table with below contents:
| id  | name | notes                                                 |
| --- | ---  | ------------------------------------------------------|
| 1   | Foo  | ## section A                                          |
|     |      |  This is first paragraph.                             |
|     |      |  This is second paragraph. Itemized lists look like:  |
|     |      |     * This is *first item*                            |
|     |      |     * This is **second item**                         |
|     |      |     * Link to [example](https://example.com)          |
  

When I build a report using Looker, I would like Looker to render markdown contents in the corresponding text box.
Is there a way to accomplish this?
There would be thousands of students and each student will have different notes.
How do I model LookML for this table? Any help is appreciated.
I would like to render markdown content stored in database. Currently, it displays the data as is without rendering it as markdown.

To render a text field, you can use the "html" parameter in the LookML Dimension definition. To do this, you should pre-mark the text with pseudo-tags, which will then be replaced with real HTML tags. It is important that at the moment the rendering of the text field works correctly only in the visualization type "Table (Legacy)"
An example of dimension for rendering your text:
dimension: notes_rendered {
  type: string
  html:{{ value | replace: '-br-', '<br/>' 
        | replace: '-h2', '<h2>' | replace: 'h2-', '</h2>' 
        | replace: '-li', '<li>' | replace: 'li-', '</li>' 
        | replace: '-i', '<i>' | replace: 'i-', '</i>' 
        | replace: '-b', '<b>' | replace: 'b-', '</b>'
        | replace: '-a', '<a href="' | replace: '--', '">' | replace: 'a-', '</a>'}};;
  sql: '-h2 section A h2-' ||
          'This is first paragraph. -br-' ||
          'This is second paragraph. Itemized lists look like: ' || 
              '-li This is -i first item i-  li-' ||
              '-li This is -b second item b- li-' ||
              '-li Link to -ahttps://www.example.com--examplea- li-' ;; 
}

Pay attention to the pseudo tags in the source text in SQL parameter
The result will look like this:

